# Intellij Idea Community Constantly Freezes and Maven projects stuck on reading pom.xml for a very long time

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have just installed Intellij Idea Community on my work computer (virtual machine) and it constantly freezes for more than a minute at times every few minutes. Additionally, when I can finally do some work and load, and when I open a maven project, the reading pom.xml stage can take 20-30 minutes. This also happens anytime I make changes to my pom.xml file.

I read a bit about the vm options but couldn't understand enough of it to make any changes.

[Google Drive Link to idea logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JucrHf3J6dTsT1Ksee9v93jE1ewJUB9l/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Maybe you gave too little memory for your virtual machine.

Comment: @Fureeish I can't control the memory allocated to the virtual machine as that is controlled by the company. But from what I can see the virtual machine has 16gb of memory

Comment: First does you build work on plain command line?

Comment: @khmarbaise yes

Comment: Please provide the thread dumps via Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data, see also https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544899. You can report the issue directly at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have edited the question with a link to the logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the maven problem by setting a proxy in intellij. This did not occur to me at first as none of the other IDEs that we use have proxies set.

As for the constant freezing, a majority of it was caused due to the maven scans and since I dont have that problem anymore, I don't need to worry too much about the freezes either

Answer (score 4):

Check your intellij memory settings. Increase it if it is low.

Go to ***Help*** -> click on ***Change Memory Settings***

In Popup increase the memory.

Click ***Save and Restart***

[image]

[image]

Comment: My heap size was set to 2gb. I changed it to 3gb but it hasn't made any difference